# How to include a model into a Yii unit test file

Tags: unit-testing, yii, phpunit

I need to include a model so I can do a - new SomeClass in my unit test. I though it will automatically do that for me but gives me an error

Class SomeClass not found

Answer (score 1):

This is because your classes are not being autoloaded to your tests ;

In your application folder you will have something like this

```
 protected/                containing protected application files
      tests/                 containing tests for the application
         fixtures/           containing database fixtures
         functional/         containing functional tests
         unit/               containing unit tests
         report/             containing coverage reports
         bootstrap.php       the script executed at the very beginning
         phpunit.xml         the PHPUnit configuration file
         WebTestCase.php     the base class for Web-based functional tests
```

The `bootstrap.php` contains the entry script which autoloads all your classes like your index.php; it will look something like this

```
$yiit='path/to/yii/framework/yiit.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/test.php';
require_once($yiit);
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/WebTestCase.php');
Yii::createWebApplication($config);
```

Check if the `path/to/framework/yiit.php` is configured to the correct directory containing the framework

You will need to store unit tests within protected/tests/unit; and ideally test classes extend from `CDbTestCase` if you are testing models

To run the tests for a class from the tests directory you run

`phpunit -- unit/MyClassTest.php`

You should read the testing chapter in the guide to understand this fully: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/test.overview

You don't *have* to use yii testing framework for unit testing; you can certainly setup `phpunit` with your own autoloaders and entry scripts to load only specific classes etc ( increases speed of your tests), however you should do this only if you know what you are doing; it is easier use Yii testing framework;